# Syntax error in sh - built and working for bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sh

I just started learning bash and have a few scripts working together fine from the command line and via udev.

However I just installed AT so I could get around some udev limitations.

It's taken me forever to first notice that **AT is very obvious about using sh** - **not bash**, and that was causing my `source` command to fail. I since replaced it with the more portable `.`, that should work with all of the shells.

But now I get a `sh syntax error` when I declare variables using brackets to surround sourced variables that have double quotes in them.

I'd like to fix this syntax error in sh `"(" unexpected` - and if someone could suggest an **alternative that works for both sh and bash**, that would be great. Otherwise a sh fix would at least get me going again.

**These are the few lines in the working bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# inlinetest.sh
#
CONFIG_FILE=/home/pi/autostart/autostart-settings.cfg

# Check if file exists
if [ ! -f "$CONFIG_FILE" ]; then
    exit 1
else
   # process stream settings - source is only in bash
   # use . for sh and bash shell functionality (AT uses sh)
  . "$CONFIG_FILE"
fi

# Function to wrap arecord and avconv into one command
pipe_cmd() {
   sudo nohup sudo /home/pi/aplay/arecord2 -f cd -D plughw:1,0 -q | /usr/bin/avconv "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
} 

stream_parameters=(-ice_name "$icecast_show" -f mp3)   
icecast_setup="icecast://$icecast_user:$icecast_password@$icecast_server:$icecast_port$icecast_mount_url"
stream_args=(-re -i - -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -content_type audio/mpeg -loglevel quiet -b:a "$stream_bitrate" -legacy_icecast "$icecast_legacy") 

pipe_cmd "${stream_args[@]}" "${stream_parameters[@]}" "$icecast_setup"
```

Syntax error occurs on this line:

```
stream_parameters=(-ice_name "$icecast_show" -f mp3)
```

and will probably do same thing on this one:

```
stream_args=(-re -i - -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -content_type audio/mpeg -loglevel quiet -b:a "$stream_bitrate" -legacy_icecast "$icecast_legacy")
```

> **EDIT**

This message is returned by ShellCheck **when I change the shell to /bin/sh**

```
In POSIX sh, arrays are undefined
```

Comment: It works fine in bash. The issue is when using sh shell. The syntax error gets described in ShellCheck as `In POSIX sh, arrays are undefined` if that helps anyone

Comment: This should have a bash tag - It is bash code and I'd like it to work in bash after it's fixed to work in sh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sh` does not have arrays (or, rather, it has only one), and `stream_parameters=(-ice_name "$icecast_show" -f mp3)` is a syntax error.  If you want to use the one array that you have available, you can do something like

```
set -- -ice_name "$icecast_show" -f mp3   
icecast_setup="icecast://$icecast_user:$icecast_password@$icecast_server:$icecast_port$icecast_mount_url"
set -- "$@" -re -i - -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -content_type audio/mpeg -loglevel quiet -b:a "$stream_bitrate" -legacy_icecast "$icecast_legacy" 


pipe_cmd "$@"  "$icecast_setup"
```

Comment: so what's happening here? The first `set` defines the "one array" and the second `set` appends to it? That should work in bash as well?

Comment: Which array does `sh` have?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm referring to the array of positional parameters. (I'm not sure it's technically an array, but you can reference it with "$@" as if it is.) @dbmitch; yes, the first sets assigns the positional parameters, and the second one appends to it.

Comment: OK — stretching it a bit, but … well, it isn't really an array because you can't use subscripts on it.  However, that explains your thought.  Looking at Bash's [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode), I don't see a prohibition on arrays in there.  And `/bin/sh` (for Bash 3.2) on Mac OS X allows `x=(a b c)` and `echo "${x[@]}"`.  OTOH, maybe `/bin/sh` is something other than `bash` — perhaps `dash` — on the OP's machine.